# Why does eclipse have such a issue importing standard python libraries

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I just moved from sublime to eclipse and ran a program which contained the time library 'Arrow'.

It first said the no module could be found, so I then I added the source folder to the PyDev python path, now it's giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\workspace\Loan_rates\master.py", line 8, in <module>
    import arrow 
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\arrow\arrow.py", line 16, in <module>
    from arrow import util, locales, parser, formatter
ImportError: cannot import name util
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you added:

`C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\arrow` to your Interpreter PYTHONPATH -- which makes it resolve `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\arrow\arrow.py` as the arrow module.

The solution is removing `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\arrow` from the PYTHONPATH -- `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` should be enough in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing the command line that works (when launched successfully from your terminal) to what PyDev is constructing.

To see the command line PyDev actually uses, open the launch configuration (*Run* menu -> *Run Configurations...* -> *Python run* -> Select your launch on the left) and in the Interpreter tab press *See resulting command-line for the given parameters*.

This is a screenshot of what I am referring to:

[image: see resulting command line screenshot]